# Помогите разобраться с webpack

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, webpack

Проблема с webpack. На данный момент выдает вот такую ошибку:
Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.

- configuration[0].module.rules[0] has an unknown property 'enforse'. These properties are valid:
  object { assert?, compiler?, dependency?, descriptionData?, enforce?, exclude?, generator?, include?, issuer?, issuerLayer?, layer?, loader?, mimetype?, oneOf?, options?, parser?, realResource?, resolve?, resource?, resourceFragment?, resourceQuery?, rules?, scheme?, sideEffects?, test?, type?, use? }

```
Содержимое файла `webpack.config.js`

const path = require('path');
const CheckerPlugin = require('awesome-typescript-loader').CheckerPlugin;
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = (env) => {
    const isDevBuild = !(env && env.prod);

    const outputDir = env && env.publishDir ? env.publishDir : __dirname;

    return [
        {
            mode: isDevBuild ? 'development' : 'production',

            devtool: 'inline-source-map',

            stats: { modules: false },

            entry: {
                App: './ClientApp/App.tsx',
            },

            watchOptions: {
                ignored: /node_modules/,
            },

            output: {
                filename: 'dist/[name].js',
                path: path.join(outputDir, 'wwwroot'),
                publicPath: '/',
            },

            resolve: {
                extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
            },

            devServer: {
                hot: true,
            },

            module: {
                rules: [
                    {
                        test: /\.tsx?$/,
                        enforse: 'pre',
                        include: /ClientApp/,
                        use: [
                            {                             
                                loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
                                options: {
                                    useCache: true,
                                    useBabel: true,
                                    babelOptions: {
                                        babelrc: false,
                                        plugins: ['react-hot-loader/babel'],
                                    },
                                },
                            },
                            'eslint-loader',
                        ],
                    },
                    {
                        test: /\.js$/i,
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                    },
                ],
            },
            plugins: [new CleanWebpackPlugin(), new CheckerPlugin()],
        },
    ];
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы неправильно настроили правила для обработки файлов - `module.rules`, см. комментарии в разделе `module.rules` ниже.

```js
const path = require('path');
const CheckerPlugin = require('awesome-typescript-loader').CheckerPlugin;
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = (env) => {
  const isDevBuild = !(env && env.prod);

  const outputDir = env && env.publishDir ? env.publishDir : __dirname;

  return [
    {
      mode: isDevBuild ? 'development' : 'production',

      devtool: 'inline-source-map',

      stats: { modules: false },

      entry: {
        App: './ClientApp/App.tsx',
      },

      watchOptions: {
        ignored: /node_modules/,
      },

      output: {
        filename: 'dist/[name].js',
        path: path.join(outputDir, 'wwwroot'),
        publicPath: '/',
      },

      resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
      },

      devServer: {
        hot: true,
      },

      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.tsx?$/,
            enforse: 'pre',
            /*loader: 'eslint-loader', перенесено на уровень выше */
            include: /ClientApp/,
            /*rules переименован в use*/
            use: [
              {
                /*rules переименован в loader*/
                loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
                options: {
                  useCache: true,
                  useBabel: true,
                  babelOptions: {
                    babelrc: false,
                    plugins: ['react-hot-loader/babel'],
                  },
                },
              },
              'eslint-loader',
              /*{ перенесено на уровень выше
                test: /\.js$/i,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
              }, */
            ],
          },
          {
            test: /\.js$/i,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
          },
        ],
      },
      plugins: [new CleanWebpackPlugin(), new CheckerPlugin()],
    },
  ];
};
```

Comment: Спасибо, я исправила настройки в соответствии с вашими комментариями. но ошибка осталась(

Comment: Пришлите ошибку

Comment: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
   - configuration[0].module.rules[0] should be one of these:
     ["..." | object { assert?, compiler?, dependency?, descriptionData?, enforce?, exclude?, generator?, include?, issuer?, issuerLayer?, layer?, loader?, mimetype?, oneOf?, options?, parser?, realResource?, resolve?, resource?, resourceFragment?, resourceQuery?, rules?, scheme?, sideEffects?, test?, type?, use? }, ...] -> A rule.
      * configuration[0].module.rules[0].loader should be a non-empty string.

Comment: A rule. * configuration[0].module.rules[0].loader should be a non-empty string. Пустая строка в первом правиле. Опубликуйте текущую конфигурацию в шапку вопроса.

Comment: Дополнил ответ с правками, комментариями пометил что именно изменил

Comment: Проблема сохраняется( обновила в шапке текущую конфигурацию

Comment: У вас теперь другая ошибка. `configuration[0].module.rules[0] has an unknown property 'enforSe'.`  Вам даже в ошибке ответ написан, должно быть `enforCe`

Comment: действительно, спасибо! но проблема не решается, возникает уже ошибка  Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration

Comment: По тексту ошибки есть аналогичный вопрос https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43037590/field-browser-doesnt-contain-a-valid-alias-configuration/43313089